# Pandas change rows in DataFrame without assignment

Tags: python, pandas

Say we have a Python Pandas DataFrame:

```
In[1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 3, 5],
                          'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]})

In[2]: print(df)
    A  B
 0  1  5
 1  1  6
 2  2  7
 3  3  8
 4  5  9
```

I want to change rows that match a certain condition. I know that this can be done via direct assignment:

```
In[3]: df[df.A==1] = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 0, 'B': 5}, 
                                   {'A': 0, 'B': 6}])

In[4]: print(df)
    A  B
 0  0  5
 1  0  6
 2  2  7
 3  3  8
 4  5  9
```

My question is: Is there an equivalent solution to the above assignment that would **return** a new DataFrame with the rows changed, i.e. a *stateless* solution? I'm looking for something like `pandas.DataFrame.assign` but which acts on rows instead of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### `DataFrame.copy`

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2[df.A == 1] = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 0, 'B': 5}, {'A': 0, 'B': 6}])
```

---

#### `DataFrame.mask` + `fillna`

```
m = df.A == 1
fill_df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 0, 'B': 5}, {'A': 0, 'B': 6}], index=df.index[m])
df2 = df.mask(m).fillna(fill_df)
```